How to write select and group statement in LINQ?
I want to know how to rewrite my query in LINQ to fetch data from the database with the use of select and group statement.



ID
Item
Qty
Amount
Date




1
Padlock
2
2.00
09/04/2024


2
Bolt
1
5.00
09/04/2024


3
Bolt
3
15.00
10/04/2024


4
Bolt
1
5.00
11/04/2024



This is what l had tried. The code below actually fetch all records from the database, but l don't how to add the select and group statement into it.
[HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {
        return new { Items = _context.OrderDetail.ToList(), Count = _context.OrderDetail.Count() };
    }
}

This is what l am expecting.



Item
Qty
Amount




Padlock
2
2.00


Bolt
5
25.00


Spanner
3
5.00




Need to get distinct names along with total quantity and total amount. Please try something like below. Replace the name of properties as you need.
var result = items
        .GroupBy(item => item.Name)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            Name = group.Key,
            TotalQty = group.Sum(item => item.Qty),
            TotalAmount = group.Sum(item => item.Amount)
        });


Thanks for the update. How can l group just only the Item? Select Item From OrderDetail Group By Item

Do you mean getting distinct items from the list?
var result = orderDetails
.GroupBy(detail => detail.Item)
.Select(group => group.Key);
